# Bloquear Acceso a Internet de un programa desde consola

Tags: python, windows10, chrome, firewall

Estoy trabajando con selenium y Python, necesito desde la consola bloquear el acceso a internet (durante unos segundos/minutos) a Chrome, no me sirve cerrarlo, ni tampoco recargarlo.

Ejemplo: imagínense que una web está dando números aleatorios a gran velocidad por segundo y ustedes necesitan parar los números que siguen para poder capturar uno específico y con él devolver una respuesta, el problema es que si el número cambia, no me deja escribir correctamente la
respuesta ..
Si bien no es exacto mí caso, necesito parar la conexión para responder a ese número en particular en un mismo momento

Comment: Apaga tu router. No conozco una forma de hacerla si quiera con python, pero puedes gacer un script en batch o bash para hacer eso.

Comment: Apagar el router no es una opción, ya que necesito seguir usando internet en el ordenador.. lo que quiero es por ejemplo usando el firewall activar y desactivar el uso de internet para un programa